# Invalid Query- Trouble Updating MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

**EDIT:**

I changed the table name from 'New Orders' to 'orders' and there is no syntax error. It's posting to the table, however it is NOT posting the integer values. The only thing it posts are zeros(0).

I tried adding double quotes around the variables ie. ".$length." but that gives me the same error as before. So it's a syntax error but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thank you all for your quick answers. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

**Original:**

I've been having the most difficult time trying to update a simple table in a MySQL database. All of my attempts to diagnose this have failed and I keep receiving the same error message:

> *Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'orders (length, width, color, quantity, total ) VALUES ('',
>   '', '', '', '')' at line 1*

I tried to fix the query, I checked to make sure all of the variables matched (even on the form) and I even re-wrote the query a couple of times; used to use `sprintf`.

Now I come to you. I know you can help me and I would greatly appreciate it (:

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require("addrow_info.php");

// Gets data from URL parameters
$length = $POST['length'];
$width = $POST['width'];
$color = $POST['color'];
$quantity = $POST['quantity'];
$total = $POST['total'];

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ("localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Insert new row with user data
$query = "INSERT INTO new orders (length, width, color, quantity, total ) VALUES     ('$length', '$width', '$color', '$quantity', '$total')";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_close();
}

?>
```

**Here is the form:**

```
<form action="addrow.php" method="post">

Size(inches)<br>Length<input type="text" name="length" id="length" size="2" class="num">
      Width<input type="text" name="width" id="width" size="2" class="num"><br>
Quantity<input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" class="num" id="quantity">
<input type="hidden" class="num" value="0.20"><br><br>


<label>Total:</label><div id="tot" class="tot"     style="width:100px;height:20px;border:1px solid black;"><br><br><br>
<input type="text" class="tot" name="total">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other answers regarding "one" of the problems with your code.

Here is another **very important** point that needs to be addressed.

```
$POST
```

This is (*called*) a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and the (**required**) underscores after the `$` sign are missing.

Change them all to `$_POST`

You have:

```
$length = $POST['length'];
$width = $POST['width'];
$color = $POST['color'];
$quantity = $POST['quantity'];
$total = $POST['total'];
```

Change to:

```
$length = $_POST['length'];
$width = $_POST['width'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
```

After noticing your **edit**:

Try putting your `$length` like this `'".$length."', '".$width."',` etc. and you also need to check what your column is set to:

- CHAR
- VARCHAR
- INT
- SMALLINT
- TINYINT
- other.

It makes a difference. Experiment with each of them.

Also, how are you entering your value into your input, are you using `"` for inches (for example) ? This could also be a factor.

An option would be to use preset numbers and have the user select from a dropdown select, checkboxes or radio buttons.

If you're going to use preset numbers, do not use dots or spaces because this will surely throw an error; use a hyphen or an underscore if possible.

Comment: Right on the dot. All of your suggestions got my database working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem accessing your table name

```
INSERT INTO new orders
          -----^
```

You **cannot** have a space here.

### Fix

Change your table name to say `new_orders` or something in your database.

and access in your PHP code like  `INSERT INTO new_orders`

<sup>Disclaimer: Stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Switch to MySQLi or PDO instead.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are numerical then they will not need quoting.  Also there is a problem with your table name `new order` This should be one word

Answer (score 0):

correct:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO orders (length, width, color, quantity, total ) VALUES     ('$length', '$width', '$color', '$quantity', '$total')";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all table name should never contain space.

I am considering that you have table name new_orders.

Single quotes not parse variable & double quotes will parse variables.

Ex.

1)  $count = 1;
    echo "The count is $count";
    //Output: The count is 1
2)  $count = 1;
    echo 'The count is $count';
   //Output: The count is $count

Refer this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Try this:

$query = "INSERT INTO new_orders (length, width, color, quantity, total ) VALUES     ('".$length."', '".$width."', '".$color."', '".$quantity."', '".$total."')";

For database column have integer data type :
(Considering length, width, quantity, total all are integer type)

$query = "INSERT INTO new_orders (length, width, color, quantity, total ) VALUES     (".$length.", ".$width.", '".$color."', ".$quantity.", ".$total.")";

Comment: Thanks for your help. I renamed the table to 'orders' and it posts to the database. But it's not posting integer values and I tried what you posted right now using the double quotes but it's giving me a syntax error. Anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Change them all to $_POST

You have:

$length = $POST['length'];
$width = $POST['width'];
$color = $POST['color'];
$quantity = $POST['quantity'];
$total = $POST['total'];

Change to:

$length = $_POST['length'];
$width = $_POST['width'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$total = $_POST['total']